# Ansible json_query, unable to find a valid syntax

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I'm trying to parse this [URL](https://www.eset.com/fr/business/remote-management/remote-administrator/download/?type=13554&tx_esetdownloads_ajax%5Bproduct%5D=87&tx_esetdownloa%20%20ds_ajax%5Bbeta%5D=0&tx_esetdownloads_ajax%5Bpage_id%5D=8329&tx_esetdownloads_ajax%5Bplugin_id%5D=725052&tx_esetdownloads_ajax%5Bproduct%5D=87&tx_esetdownloads_ajax%5Bbeta%5D=0%20%20&tx_esetdownloads_ajax%5Bpage_id%5D=8329&tx_esetdownloads_ajax%5Bplugin_id%5D=725052) to get the latest version of the Agent

On Jsonquerytool dot com, I'm able to find a valid query :
`$.files.installer[?(@.component == "Agent" && @.os_group == "192")].full_version`

I'm now trying into Ansible

```yaml
  - name: "Identify latest version"
    run_once: true
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    uri:
      url: "https://www.eset.com/fr/business/remote-management/remote-administrator/download/?type=13554&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[product]=87&tx_esetdownloa  ds_ajax[beta]=0&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[page_id]=8329&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[plugin_id]=725052&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[product]=87&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[beta]=0  &tx_esetdownloads_ajax[page_id]=8329&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[plugin_id]=725052"
      method: GET
      return_content: yes
      status_code: 200
      headers:
        Accept: application/json
    register: latest_era_version_raw
  
  - name: latest_era_version
    set_fact:
      latest_era_version: "{{ (latest_era_version_raw.json|json_query(jsonq)) }}"
    vars:
      jsonq: 'files.installer[?(@.component == "Agent" && @.os_group == "192")].full_version'  # 192 = x86_64 | 225 = i686
```

But this return nothings. Also replacing my filter `[?(@.component == "Agent" && @.os_group == "192")]`with a wildcard `.*.` return the full_version list

Comment: "Jsonquerytool dot com" is not JMESPath, so you're using the wrong language. Try https://jmespath.org/

Answer (score 2):

The JMESPath query you are looking for is:

```
files.installer.* | [?component == `Agent` && os_group == '192'].full_version | [0]
```

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - uri:
       url: "https://www.eset.com/fr/business/remote-management/remote-administrator/download/?type=13554&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[product]=87&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[beta]=0&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[page_id]=8329&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[plugin_id]=725052&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[product]=87&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[beta]=0&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[page_id]=8329&tx_esetdownloads_ajax[plugin_id]=725052"
      register: latest_era_version_raw

    - set_fact:
        latest_era_version: "{{ latest_era_version_raw.json | json_query(query) }}"
      vars: 
        query: "files.installer.* | [?component == `Agent` && os_group == '192'].full_version | [0]"
    
    - debug:
        var: latest_era_version
```

This gives as a recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [uri] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  latest_era_version: 8.1.2209.0

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```